# Add users logged in through Python Social Auth to a group

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

When users are signed up through Python Social Auth, they get created as users in my database, which is fine and dandy, however I want them to be added to a certain group upon user creation.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm geeting the same issues trying to add a user in a group using python-social-auth

The error: 'function' object has no attribute connect

Here is my myapp.pipeline.py

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import Signal
from social.pipeline.user import *

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from social.utils import module_member

def new_users_handler(sender, user, response, details, **kwargs):
    user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='candidates'))

user_details.connect(new_users_handler, sender=None)
```

And my app.settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'companies.pipeline.new_users_handler',
)
```

So to make a workaround, I did the following:

Step 1: Kept the python-social-auth pipeline (without 'companies.pipeline.new_users_handler')

Step 2: in settings.py added SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL = '/social/success/'

Step 3: added a url for the /social/success/

Step 4: added a function in views.py like

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def socialsuccess(request):
    defaultgroup = Group.objects.get(name = 'name')
    user = request.user
    user.groups.add(defaultgroup)

    return render(request, 'app/social-success.html')
```

It works just fine. But I still think this is not the best approach.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

For:

- social_auth_core: 4.0.3
- social_auth_app_django: 4.0.0

You need to create a file to hold your custom pipelines (eg company.social_auth_pipelines.py) and then add to that the following function:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

def new_users_handler(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='students'))
```

You then need to register the pipeline with social core, so in your settings.py, find the SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE entry and add your pipeline to it. I added mine just below social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user eg:

```
...
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'company.social_auth_pipelines.new_users_handler',
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a new user signal on django-social-auth

```
from social_auth.signals import socialauth_registered

def new_users_handler(sender, user, response, details, **kwargs):
    user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='mygroup'))

socialauth_registered.connect(new_users_handler, sender=None)
```

This code is not tested (I'm not on my computer now) but it should give you an idea.

Comment: I'm using python social auth, not django social auth, so where is the signal located at exactly?

Comment: Ok, I assume this because you are using the django-socialauth tag

Comment: And sorry but the signals of django social auth have been deprecated, see: http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deprecated.html

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using Python Social Auth and might need to add User to some Group, here is the code I use:

```
#pipeline.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

def save_to_group(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    defaultgroup = Group.objects.get(name = 'blah')
    user.groups.add(defaultgroup)
```

And add it to SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE

```
#settings.py
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = {
  ...
  'app_name.pipeline.save_to_group'
}
```